# Failed to create a service principal. You can use an existing service principal or try again later

Tags: azure-aks

I am trying to create AKS but I receive: Failed to create a service principal. You can use an existing service principal or try again later.

The official Azure support forewords me here.

Comment: So what is the problem you have?

Comment: As far as the support explained me, I do not have sufficient privileges to create a new service principal using my corporate account because the AD I belong is not created by me despite of I am administrator of my free subscription.

Answer (score 3):

When creating the Kubernetes resource, under the authorization tab, switch the radio box from `server principal` -> `system-assigned managed identity`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I switched directory to my Azure AD ... that got me around the error above

Comment: how did you switch directory to azure ad